# Upload file to Skydrive with special characters and spaces

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, upload, onedrive, live-sdk

I am using LiveSDK for Windows Phone 8 (latest SDK version) to upload files:

```
LiveOperationResult res = await liveClient.BackgroundUploadAsync(_skyDriveFolderId, new Uri("/shared/transfers/" + myLocalFilename, UriKind.Relative), OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
```

This works fine when `myLocalFilename` contains only normal ASCII characters like "fileTEST1234.zip". But when the filename contains spaces, or special characters such as "ä", "ß", etc. then an empty (0 Bytes) file is uploaded to SkyDrive (the name of the remote file is correct). So I think there is something going wrong when the local string file name is converted to an Uri object.

One option would be to create a temporary local file copy with a standard name, upload this, and rename it to the other name on SkyDrive.

Are there better ways to fix this problem?